# How can I distribute an Access database 2010/2013? (Not Sign and Package)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to know which ways I can use to distribute an Access Database.
I'm developing an Access database split for distribute to many customers but I want to do something similar to an .exe file.

One file that contains:

- Front-end
- Database
- Pictures
- References
- Templates

...

And other things.

I want one file that executes some instructions before opening my application, actions like: Create a folder in My Documents and copying files there,
check serial number of hard drive and continue if its authorized or stop it if not authorized, links FE and DB, encrypt database. (I have this coding in vba).

Can you help me?

Comment: Hi And welcome to SO. Please follow [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to ask a better received question.

Comment: Hi and thanks. I think this clearly explained the situation. Can you tell me where is the mistake? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You need a program that creates an installer (or setup program). [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is the first that comes to mind.

It even has its own [SO tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inno-setup). :)

Your setup must first check if Access (in a suitable version) is installed, and if not, install the Access Runtime.